# Bash: infinite sleep (infinite blocking)

Tags: linux, bash, sleep, infinite

I use `startx` to start X which will evaluate my `.xinitrc`. In my `.xinitrc` I start my window manager using `/usr/bin/mywm`. Now, if I kill my WM (in order to f.e. test some other WM), X will terminate too because the `.xinitrc` script reached EOF.
So I added this at the end of my `.xinitrc`:

```
while true; do sleep 10000; done
```

This way X won't terminate if I kill my WM. Now my question: how can I do an **infinite sleep** instead of looping sleep? Is there a command which will kinda like freeze the script?

Comment: Interesting... "sleep infinity" to keep X awake :-)

Comment: I like the irony in it

Answer (score 516, accepted):

`sleep infinity`, if implemented, will either sleep forever or sleep for the maximum sleep length, depending on the implementation.  (see other answers and comments for this question that mention some of the variations)

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately my busybox does not understand.

Comment: BSD (or at least OS X) doesn't understand `sleep infinity` either, though it was a cool thing to learn about for Linux. However, `while true; do sleep 86400; done` ought to be an adequate substitute.

Comment: Regarding this, I made some research I documented in a separate answer. To summarize: `infinity` is converted in C from "string" to a `double`. Then that `double` is truncated to the maximum values allowed `timespec`, which means a very large amount of seconds (architecture-dependant) but, in theory, finite.

Comment: I googled "cat abuse". Not sure what I was expecting to find. How about: "No cats were harmed in the execution of this script"

Comment: FWIW, macOS Big Sur now understands "sleep infinity" though Mojave did not. (I skipped Catalina.)

Comment: `/bin/sleep infinity` does _not_ work on the Big Sur I'm using. However, `gsleep infinity` does.

Comment: If your OS doesn't support `sleep infinity` then I suggest running `sleep 365d` assuming your box is restarted at least once a year.

Comment: @jp48 `sleep infinity` will now actually sleep forever with the latest GNU coreutils.

Comment: Probably what happened is that @Glenn linked the GNU utils like so, then forgot. I certainly have and have become confused before: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20use%20these%20commands%20with%20their%20normal%20names%2C%20you%20can%20add%20a%20%22gnubin%22%20directory%20to%20your%20PATH%20with%3A%0A%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0PATH%3D%22%24(brew%20%2D%2Dprefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin%3A%24PATH%22

Comment: Apologies to @kojiro and all for the bad/misleading info re: `sleep infinity` and Big Sur. I was on Big Sur at the time, and would have posted without attribution only if I had tested it myself, but alas I do not know why it worked for me then; perhaps it was as @ijoseph suggests. Again, though, I apologize for the bad/misleading info.

Answer (score 110):

## `tail` does not block

As always:  For everything there is an answer which is short, easy to understand, easy to follow and completely wrong.  Here `tail -f /dev/null` falls into this category ;)

If you look at it with `strace tail -f /dev/null`, you will notice that this solution is far from blocking!  It's probably even worse than the `sleep` solution in the question, as it uses (under Linux) precious resources like the `inotify` system.  Also other processes which write to `/dev/null` make `tail` loop.  (On my Ubuntu64 16.10 this adds several 10 syscalls per second on an already busy system.)

## The question was for a blocking command

### Unfortunately, there is no such thing...

Read: I do not know any way to achieve this with the shell directly.

Everything (even `sleep infinity`) can be interrupted by some signal.  So if you want to be really sure it does not exceptionally return, it must run in a loop, like you already did for your `sleep`.  Please note, that (on Linux) `/bin/sleep` apparently is capped at 24 days (have a look at `strace sleep infinity`), hence the best you can do is probably:

```
while :; do sleep 2073600; done
```

(Note that I believe `sleep` loops internally for higher values than 24 days, but this means:  It is not blocking, it is very slowly looping.  So why not move this loop to the outside?)

### ...but you can come quite near with an unnamed `fifo`

You can create something which really blocks as long as there are no signals sent to the process.  Following uses `bash 4`, 2 PIDs and 1 `fifo`:

```
bash -c 'coproc { exec >&-; read; }; eval exec "${COPROC[0]}<&-"; wait'
```

You can check that this really blocks with `strace` if you like:

```
strace -ff bash -c '..see above..'
```

#### How this was constructed

`read` blocks if there is no input data (see some other answers).  However, the `tty` (aka. `stdin`) usually is not a good source, as it is closed when the user logs out.  Also it might steal some input from the `tty`.  Not nice.

To make `read` block, we need to wait for something like a `fifo` which will never return anything.  In `bash 4` there is a command which can provide us with exactly such a `fifo`: `coproc`.  If we also wait the blocking `read` (which is our `coproc`), we are done.  Sadly this needs to keep open two PIDs and a `fifo`.

#### Variant with a named `fifo`

If you do not bother using a named `fifo`, you can do this as follows:

```
mkfifo "$HOME/.pause.fifo" 2>/dev/null; read <"$HOME/.pause.fifo"
```

Not using a loop on the read is a bit sloppy, but you can reuse this `fifo` as often as you like and make the `read`s terminate using `touch "$HOME/.pause.fifo"` (if there is more than a single read waiting, all are terminated at once).

### Or use the Linux `pause()` syscall

For the infinite blocking, there is a Linux system call named `pause()` which does what we want:  Wait forever (until a signal arrives).  However there is no userspace program for this (yet).

#### C

Creating such a program is easy.  Here is a snippet to create a very small Linux program called `pause` which pauses indefinitely (needs a C compiler such as `gcc`, and uses `diet` etc. to produce a small binary):

```
printf '#include <unistd.h>\nint main(){for(;;)pause();}' > pause.c;
diet -Os cc pause.c -o pause;
strip -s pause;
ls -al pause
```

#### `python`

If you do not want to compile something yourself, but you have `python` installed, you can use this under Linux:

```
python -c 'while 1: import ctypes; ctypes.CDLL(None).pause()'
```

(Note: Use `exec python -c ...` to replace the current shell, this frees one PID.  The solution can be improved with some IO redirection as well, freeing unused FDs.  This is up to you.)

How this works: `ctypes.CDLL(None)` [loads the "main program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878901/how-does-ctypes-cdll-loadlibrarynone-work) (including the C library) and runs the `pause()` function from it, all within a loop.  Less efficient than the C version, but works.

## My recommendation for you:

Stay at the looping sleep.  It's easy to understand, very portable, and blocks for most of the time.

Comment: @Andrew Normally you do not need the `trap` (which modifies the behavior of the shell to signals) nor the background (which allows the shell to intercept signals from the terminal, like Strg+C).  So `sleep infinity` is enough (behaves like `exec sleep infinity` if it is the last statement. to see the difference use `strace -ffDI4 bash -c 'YOURCODEHERE'`).  The looping sleep is better, because `sleep` can return in certain circumstances.  For example you do not want X11 to shut down suddenly on a `killall sleep`, just because `.xstartup` ends in `sleep infinity` instead of a sleep loop.

Comment: May be a little obscure, but [`s6-pause`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6-portable-utils/s6-pause.html) is a userland command to run `pause()`, optionally ignoring various signals.

Comment: @Tino `/bin/sleep` is not capped at 24 days as you say. It would be nice if you could update that. On Linux right now, [this code](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/66a7f1c706907612a260565cec36b1740caf8a48/lib/nanosleep.c#L65) is active. It caps individual `nanosleep()` syscalls to 24 days, but calls them in a loop. So `sleep infinity` should not exit after 24 days. The `double` positive infinity gets converted to a `struct timespec`. Looking at `rpl_nanosleep` in GDB, `infinity` gets converted to `{ tv_sec = 9223372036854775807, tv_nsec = 999999999 }` on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @nh2 It was already mentioned in the text that sleep *probably* loops instead of being fully blocking.  I edited it now slightly to hopefully make this fact a bit more clear.  Please note this "*probably*", because from `strace` alone I cannot prove the fact that there is really some looping code compiled in `sleep`, and I do not want to wait 24 days just to test this (or decompile `/bin/sleep`).  It is always better to program defensively, if there is no hard mathematical proof, that something really is, as it seems to be.  Also never trust anything: `killall -9 sleep`

Comment: The pause() option can be done pretty easily with perl:
perl -MPOSIX -e 'pause()'

Comment: `sleep` isn't really capped to 24 days. It breaks the interval into 24-day segments to work around bugs in some operating systems: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/nanosleep.c?h=8cc34c349afc79e2728093e109a09f9f0aaa4b50#n50

Comment: In the next coreutils, `sleep infinity` will now actually sleep forever without looping: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2020-02/msg00081.html

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev nice!  `sleep inf` then will call `pause()` which gives us all we want.  Afterwards my answer can be retired ;)

Comment: This answer reminds me why I love Stack Overflow lol

Comment: Even if your system supports `sleep infinity`, you might want to execute that in an infinite loop because sleep may be interrupted by some signals and if it's important to keep blocking, you have to enter the sleep again after a wakeup.

Comment: If you're on a server where the admins have set TMOUT, read doesn't help a lot here. Sleep is still better, I think.

Answer (score 75):

Maybe this seems ugly, but why not just run `cat` and let it wait for input forever?

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't have a hanging pipe from which to read. Please advise.

Comment: @Matt, maybe make a pipe and `cat` it? `mkfifo pipe && cat pipe`

Comment: What @twalberg says, but additionally you can immediately reassign to 3 and unlink it, as shown here: https://superuser.com/a/633185/762481

Answer (score 57):

TL;DR: since GNU coreutils version 9, `sleep infinity` does the right thing on Linux systems. Previously (and in other systems) the implementation was to actually sleep the maximum time allowed, which is finite.

---

Wondering why this is not documented anywhere, I bothered to read the [sources from GNU coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sleep.c) and I found it executes roughly what follows:

1. Use [`strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) from C stdlib on the first argument to convert 'infinity' to a double precision value. So, assuming IEEE 754 double precision the 64-bit *positive infinity* value is stored in the `seconds` variable.
2. Invoke `xnanosleep(seconds)` ([found in gnulib](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/xnanosleep.c#)), this in turn invokes `dtotimespec(seconds)` ([also in gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/f42d5af5ba76970309c5704db1c229143043bcc0/lib/dtotimespec.c#L35))  to convert from `double` to `struct timespec`.
3. [`struct timespec`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec) is just a pair of numbers: integer part (in seconds) and fractional part (in nanoseconds).
   Naïvely converting *positive infinity* to integer would result in undefined behaviour (see [§6.3.1.4 from C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=55)), so instead it truncates to `TYPE_MAXIMUM(time_t)`.
4. The actual value of `TYPE_MAXIMUM(time_t)` is not set in the standard (even `sizeof(time_t)` isn't); so, for the sake of example let's pick x86-64 from a recent Linux kernel.

This is `TIME_T_MAX` in the Linux kernel, which is defined ([`time.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/linux/time.h)) as:

```
(time_t)((1UL << ((sizeof(time_t) << 3) - 1)) - 1)
```

Note that `time_t` is `__kernel_time_t` and `time_t` is `long`; the LP64 data model is used, so `sizeof(long)` is 8 (64 bits).

Which results in: `TIME_T_MAX = 9223372036854775807`.

That is: `sleep infinite` results in an actual sleep time of 9223372036854775807 seconds (10^11 years). And for 32-bit linux systems (`sizeof(long)` is 4 (32 bits)): 2147483647 seconds (68 years; see also [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)).

---

**Edit**: apparently the `nanoseconds` function called is not directly the syscall, but an OS-dependent wrapper (also [defined in gnulib](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/d4f6a210f44a2bbfedfc60353758c39fb86f8d7a/lib/nanosleep.c#L43)).

There's an extra step as a result: for some systems where `HAVE_BUG_BIG_NANOSLEEP` is `true` the sleep is truncated to 24 days and then called in a loop. This is the case for some (or all?) Linux distros. Note that this wrapper may be not used if a *configure*-time test succeeds ([source](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/d4f6a210f44a2bbfedfc60353758c39fb86f8d7a/m4/nanosleep.m4#L46)).

In particular, that would be `24 * 24 * 60 * 60 = 2073600 seconds` (plus 999999999 nanoseconds); but this is called in a loop in order to respect the specified total sleep time. Therefore the previous conclusions remain valid.

---

In conclusion, the resulting sleep time **is not infinite but high enough for all practical purposes**, even if the resulting actual time lapse is not portable; that depends on the OS and architecture.

To answer the original question, this is obviously good enough but if for some reason (a *very* resource-constrained system) you really want to avoid an useless extra countdown timer, I guess the most correct alternative is to use the `cat` method described in other answers.

**Edit**: recent GNU coreutils versions will try to use the `pause` syscall (if available) instead of looping. The previous argument is no longer valid when targeting these newer versions in Linux (and possibly BSD).

---

#### Portability

This is an important and valid concern:

- `sleep infinity` is a GNU coreutils extension not contemplated [in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html). GNU's implementation also supports a "fancy" syntax for time durations, like `sleep 1h 5.2s` while POSIX only allows a positive integer (e.g. `sleep 0.5` is **not** allowed).
- Some compatible implementations: GNU coreutils, FreeBSD (at least from version [8.2](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sleep&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)?), Busybox (requires to be compiled with options `FANCY_SLEEP` and `FLOAT_DURATION`).
- The `strtod` behaviour is C and POSIX compatible (i.e. `strtod("infinity", 0)` is always valid in C99-conformant implementations, [see §7.20.1.3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#page=320)).

---

Comment: In the next coreutils, `sleep infinity` will now actually sleep forever without looping: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2020-02/msg00081.html

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev more than two years later, is the "next coreutils" already available? If so, what is the version? (I tried looking into the link for a version number but didn't find any.) Thank you!

Comment: @PedroA It should be in coreutils 9.

Comment: I just checked, sleep on FreeBSD 13.1-RELEASE does not support `infinity`.

Answer (score 14):

`sleep infinity` looks most elegant, but sometimes it doesn't work for some reason. In that case, you can try other blocking commands such as `cat`, `read`, `tail -f /dev/null`, `grep a` etc.

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null` was also a working solution for me on a SaaS platform

Comment: `tail -f /dev/null` also has the advantage of not consuming stdin. I have used it for that reason.

Comment: Those considering this option should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655546/1594286) to learn about the ramifications of this option.

Answer (score 13):

Let me explain why `sleep infinity` works though it is not documented. [jp48's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45396600/8776746) is also useful.

The most important thing: By specifying `inf` or `infinity` (both case-insensitive), you can sleep for the longest time your implementation permits (i.e. the smaller value of `HUGE_VAL` and `TYPE_MAXIMUM(time_t)`).

Now let's dig into the details. The source code of `sleep` command can be read from [coreutils/src/sleep.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/sleep.c). Essentially, the function does this:

```cpp
double s; //seconds
xstrtod (argv[i], &p, &s, cl_strtod); //`p` is not essential (just used for error check).
xnanosleep (s);
```

### Understanding `xstrtod (argv[i], &p, &s, cl_strtod)`

**`xstrtod()`**

According to [gnulib/lib/xstrtod.c](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/xstrtod.c), the call of `xstrtod()` converts string `argv[i]` to a floating point value and stores it to `*s`, using a converting function `cl_strtod()`.

**`cl_strtod()`**

As can be seen from [coreutils/lib/cl-strtod.c](https://fossies.org/linux/coreutils/lib/cl-strtod.c), `cl_strtod()` converts a string to a floating point value, using `strtod()`.

**`strtod()`**

According to `man 3 strtod`, `strtod()` converts a string to a value of type `double`. The manpage says

> The  expected  form  of the (initial portion of the) string is ... or (iii) an infinity, or ...

and an infinity is defined as

> An infinity is either "INF" or "INFINITY", disregarding case.

Although the document tells

> If the correct value would cause overflow, plus or minus `HUGE_VAL` (`HUGE_VALF`, `HUGE_VALL`) is returned

, it is not clear how an infinity is treated. So let's see the source code [gnulib/lib/strtod.c](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/strtod.c). What we want to read is

```cpp
else if (c_tolower (*s) == 'i'
         && c_tolower (s[1]) == 'n'
         && c_tolower (s[2]) == 'f')
  {
    s += 3;
    if (c_tolower (*s) == 'i'
        && c_tolower (s[1]) == 'n'
        && c_tolower (s[2]) == 'i'
        && c_tolower (s[3]) == 't'
        && c_tolower (s[4]) == 'y')
      s += 5;
    num = HUGE_VAL;
    errno = saved_errno;
  }
```

Thus, `INF` and `INFINITY` (both case-insensitive) are regarded as `HUGE_VAL`.

**`HUGE_VAL` family**

Let's use [N1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) as the C standard. `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF` and `HUGE_VALL` macros are defined in §7.12-3

> The macro
>       `HUGE_VAL`
>   expands to a positive double constant expression, not necessarily representable as a float. The macros
>       `HUGE_VALF`
>       `HUGE_VALL`
>   are respectively float and long double analogs of `HUGE_VAL`.
>   
>   `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF`, and `HUGE_VALL` can be positive infinities in an implementation that supports infinities.

and in §7.12.1-5

> If a floating result overflows and default rounding is in effect, then the function returns the value of the macro `HUGE_VAL`, `HUGE_VALF`, or `HUGE_VALL` according to the return type

### Understanding `xnanosleep (s)`

Now we understand all essence of `xstrtod()`. From the explanations above, it is crystal-clear that `xnanosleep(s)` we've seen first actually means `xnanosleep(HUGE_VALL)`.

**`xnanosleep()`**

According to the source code [gnulib/lib/xnanosleep.c](https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/xnanosleep.c), `xnanosleep(s)` essentially does this:

```cpp
struct timespec ts_sleep = dtotimespec (s);
nanosleep (&ts_sleep, NULL);
```

**`dtotimespec()`**

This function converts an argument of type `double` to an object of type `struct timespec`. Since it is very simple, let me cite the source code [gnulib/lib/dtotimespec.c](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/dtotimespec.c). All of the comments are added by me.

```cpp
struct timespec
dtotimespec (double sec)
{
  if (! (TYPE_MINIMUM (time_t) < sec)) //underflow case
    return make_timespec (TYPE_MINIMUM (time_t), 0);
  else if (! (sec < 1.0 + TYPE_MAXIMUM (time_t))) //overflow case
    return make_timespec (TYPE_MAXIMUM (time_t), TIMESPEC_HZ - 1);
  else //normal case (looks complex but does nothing technical)
    {
      time_t s = sec;
      double frac = TIMESPEC_HZ * (sec - s);
      long ns = frac;
      ns += ns < frac;
      s += ns / TIMESPEC_HZ;
      ns %= TIMESPEC_HZ;

      if (ns < 0)
        {
          s--;
          ns += TIMESPEC_HZ;
        }

      return make_timespec (s, ns);
    }
}
```

Since `time_t` is defined as an integral type (see §7.27.1-3), it is natural we assume the maximum value of type `time_t` is smaller than `HUGE_VAL` (of type `double`), which means we enter the overflow case. (Actually this assumption is not needed since, in all cases, the procedure is essentially the same.)

**`make_timespec()`**

The last wall we have to climb up is `make_timespec()`. Very fortunately, it is so simple that citing the source code [gnulib/lib/timespec.h](http://www.opencoverage.net/coreutils/index_html/source_191.html) is enough.

```cpp
_GL_TIMESPEC_INLINE struct timespec
make_timespec (time_t s, long int ns)
{
  struct timespec r;
  r.tv_sec = s;
  r.tv_nsec = ns;
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

What about sending a [SIGSTOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP) to itself?

This should pause the process until SIGCONT is received. Which is in your case: never.

```
kill -STOP "$$";
# grace time for signal delivery
sleep 60;
```

Comment: Signals are asynchronous. So the following can happen: a) shell calls kill b) kill tells kernel that shell shall receive signal STOP c) kill terminates and returns to shell d) shell continues (maybe terminates because script ends) e) kernel finally finds the time to deliver signal STOP to shell

Comment: @temple Great insight, didn't think about the asynchronous nature of signals. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I recently had a need to do this. I came up with the following function that will allow bash to sleep forever without calling any external program:

```
snore()
{
    local IFS
    [[ -n "${_snore_fd:-}" ]] || { exec {_snore_fd}<> <(:); } 2>/dev/null ||
    {
        # workaround for MacOS and similar systems
        local fifo
        fifo=$(mktemp -u)
        mkfifo -m 700 "$fifo"
        exec {_snore_fd}<>"$fifo"
        rm "$fifo"
    }
    read ${1:+-t "$1"} -u $_snore_fd || :
}
```

NOTE: I previously posted a version of this that would open and close the file descriptor each time, but I found that on some systems doing this hundreds of times a second would eventually lock up. Thus the new solution keeps the file descriptor between calls to the function. Bash will clean it up on exit anyway.

This can be called just like /bin/sleep, and it will sleep for the requested time. Called without parameters, it will hang forever.

```
snore 0.1  # sleeps for 0.1 seconds
snore 10   # sleeps for 10 seconds
snore      # sleeps forever
```

[There's a writeup with excessive details on my blog here](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/sleeping-without-a-subprocess-in-bash-and-how-to-sleep-forever)

Answer (score 3):

This approach will not consume any resources for keeping process alive.

```sh
while :; do :; done & kill -STOP $! && wait
```

#### Breakdown

- `while :; do :; done &` Creates a dummy process in background
- `kill -STOP $!` Stops the background process
- `wait` Wait for the background process, this will be blocking forever, cause background process was stopped before

#### Notes

- works only from within a script file.

Comment: It will lead to busy waiting(100% CPU) on MacOS.

Comment: @Miao1007 it only happens with zsh with sh this does not happen. I don't have any clue why this happens in zsh.

Comment: @Miao1007 I got it, its because `wait` in zsh will resume the given process.

Comment: @Miao1007 I fixed my command by removing `$!` form `wait` command. Now its working in `zsh` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of killing the window manager, try running the new one with `--replace` or `-replace` if available.

Comment: If I use `--replace` I always get a warning like `another window manager is already running`. That doesn't make much sense to me tho.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep inf` can save you some typing, it's the same as `sleep infinity`

Answer (score -3):

```
while :; do read; done
```

no waiting for child sleeping process.

Comment: This eats `stdin` if this still happens to be connected to the `tty`.  If you run it with `< /dev/null` it busy-loops.  It might be of some use in certain situations, so I do not downvote.

Comment: This is a very bad idea, it will just consume alllot of cpu.