# How can I keep a container running on Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm now trying to run a simple container with shell (/bin/bash) on a Kubernetes cluster.

I thought that there was a way to keep a container running on a Docker container by using `pseudo-tty` and detach option (`-td` option on `docker run` command).

For example,

```
$ sudo docker run -td ubuntu:latest
```

Is there an option like this in Kubernetes?

I've tried running a container by using a `kubectl run-container` command like:

```
kubectl run-container test_container ubuntu:latest --replicas=1
```

But the container exits for a few seconds (just like launching with the `docker run` command without options I mentioned above). And ReplicationController launches it again repeatedly.

Is there a way to keep a container running on Kubernetes like the `-td` options in the `docker run` command?

Comment: Using this image (as [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#dns) suggests) is quite handy: `kubectl run curl --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty`

Comment: This question has been mentioned at this video: [Kubernetes the very hard way at Datadog](https://youtu.be/2dsCwp_j0yQ?t=2150) with a slide-title of *"Cargo culting*. From wikipedia: The term *cargo cult programmer* may apply when an unskilled or novice computer programmer (or one inexperienced with the problem at hand) copies some program code from one place to another with little or no understanding of how it works or whether it is required in its new position.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm still pretty early in my Kubernetes learning, but mentioning this as Cargo Culting seems unfair. There is a _very_ good reason why you might want a Kubernetes pod to live forever (or, until manually killed) - if you want to test the networking within the cluster using tools, environment, etc. available within a pod. Yes, you _could_ repeatedly spin up short-lived pods executing the commands you want, but isn't it easier to start a persistent pod and start a shell on it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

A container exits when its main process exits. Doing something like:

```
docker run -itd debian
```

to hold the container open is frankly a hack that should only be used for quick tests and examples. If you just want a container for testing for a few minutes, I would do:

```
docker run -d debian sleep 300
```

Which has the advantage that the container will automatically exit if you forget about it. Alternatively, you could put something like this in a `while` loop to keep it running forever, or just run an application such as `top`. All of these should be easy to do in Kubernetes.

The real question is why would you want to do this? Your container should be providing a service, whose process will keep the container running in the background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm now trying to understand the behavior of containers, with dozens of containers running at the same time. Endless loop and using other heavy command, prevent me to know what is the behavior of containers. That is the reason why I need simple container like only running /bin/bash.

Comment: For now, I'll try running `cat` without arguments and `top` and `sleep` with argument of large number.

Comment: `sleep infinity` works in a lot of cases (not busybox)

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to do this. For example, you might deploy your pods with helm releases and injected configuration, which is going to make recreation of similar environments annoying and cumbersome. But having a container with that configuration in cases where the other pods crash/are deleted can be infinitely useful.

Comment: Because my _service_ consists of multiple processes.

Comment: @Adrian: I thought Container is a process inside the Node, which is a VM. I am bit confused with all this basic concept. Even opened a question for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230733/node-is-a-vm-container-is-a-process-then-how-container-runs-many-processes-et............ if you have got some time to look at it, and answer if it's not too stupid to answer..

Comment: @КонстантинВан Hey, younger me! You want to make a _Pod_ instead! You don't put everything in a single "_container_."

Comment: _"The real question is why would you want to do this?"_ - debugging. Maybe your service isn't immediately crashing, so you need to keep the container alive while you check everything internally (by interactively executing a shell, for example).

Answer (score 351):

Containers are meant to run to completion.  You need to provide your container with a task that will never finish.  Something like this should work:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    # Just spin & wait forever
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
```

Comment: But is this a best practice?

Comment: @aneeshjoshi I wouldn't say this is _best practice_. This is just an example providing a pod that will run without immediately exiting.  Best practice is to create your containers to do the job they were designed for (a job that runs to completion, a webserver that runs perpetually, etc.).  I posted this as an example because Kubernetes can feel initially frustrating when you keep creating pods only to have the disappear since the default command exits immediately.

Comment: @JoelB Thanks. I was wondering what is the "right" way of doing it.

Comment: thanks for this as I am in need of a container that can live for awhile allowing me to enter it. I was trying to do the same with a lighter image than `ubuntu` and tried `bash` image but couldn't get it to work. Any idea how to do the same as this with `bash` image?

Comment: I know this is an old issue; however, Kubernetes is started to support ephemeral containers. link:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/. These containers have some limitations like resource limits, however they are designed for debugging purposes.

Comment: @cryanbhu For a lighter image, you may use alpine, the container spec can look like: `{"name": "util", "image": "alpine", "command": [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "--" ], "args": [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]}` (only json because the yaml won't format in comments here.) The important bit being `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.

Comment: "are meant to run to completion"?

Comment: should `CMD` command at Dockerfile be a better approach? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710589/2042014) ref

Comment: Can you please explain what "-c --" flags are? I'm curious to learn more about it.

Comment: It's an argument to the BASH shell, telling it that everything after it should be viewed as executable and not flags to the shell.

Answer (score 219):

You could use this CMD in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

This will keep your container alive until it is told to stop. Using trap and wait will make your container **react immediately to a stop request**. Without trap/wait stopping will take a few seconds.

For busybox based images (used in alpine based images) sleep does not know about the infinity argument. This workaround gives you the same **immediate** response to a `docker stop` like in the above example:

```
CMD exec /bin/sh -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep 9999999999d & wait"
```

Comment: I'm using the same on kubernetes deployment yaml for debugging purposes

Comment: this gives me "sleep: invalid number 'infinity'"

Comment: @arunkjn Thanks for this. You are probably stuck with an image that uses busybox (like alpine images). See the updated answer.

Comment: Instead of sleep infinity, just use sleep 999999999d where d indicates days.

Comment: Thank you for the info on trapping `TERM`/`INT`! I couldn't understand why my container wasn't stopping correctly, since `sleep` will respond to it from the terminal

Comment: If someone has working `args` version for Kubernetes YAML that would be superb.
UPDATE:
Use this: `command: ["/bin/bash"]` and `args: ["-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]`

Comment: It's often preferred to use the ["json array"] syntax for CMD.
If that's what you need, you could write it this way: `CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "exec /bin/bash -c 'trap : TERM INT; sleep 9999999999d & wait'"]`

Answer (score 75):

1. In your Dockerfile use this command:

   ```
   CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"]
   ```
2. Build your docker image.
3. Push it to your cluster or similar, just to make sure the image it's available.
4. ```
   kubectl run debug-container -it --image=<your-image>
   ```

Comment: Great tips for debugging the container.

Comment: Do you need the `sh -c`? I'm pretty sure thie does the trick too: `CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]`

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch, I doubt, but still think that in case you write it without `sh -c` and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 67):

The simplest command as it can be for k8s pod manifest to run container forever:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    # Just sleep forever
    command: [ "sleep" ]
    args: [ "infinity" ]
```

Comment: The most elegant and minimalistic solution.

Comment: Getting an error with that exact code 
```The Pod "ubuntu" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)
```

Comment: It means you're trying to change part of manifest which is immutable (with kubectl apply). Try with `kubectl replace` with optional `--force` flag

Answer (score 65):

In order to keep a POD running it should to be performing certain task, otherwise Kubernetes will find it unnecessary, therefore it stops. There are many ways to keep a POD running.

I have faced similar problems when I needed a POD just to run continuously without doing any useful operation. The following are the two ways those worked for me:

1. Running sleep command while running the container.
2. Running an infinite loop inside the container.

Although the first option is easier than the second one and may suffice the requirement, it is not the best option. As, there is a limit as far as the number of seconds you are going to assign in the sleep command.
But a container with infinite loop running inside it never exits.

However, I will describe both the ways(Considering you are running busybox container):

**1. Sleep Command**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 1000"]
```

**2. Infinite Loop**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  labels:
    app: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 5 ; done"]
```

Run the following command to run the pod:

```
kubectl apply -f <pod-yaml-file-name>.yaml
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: May I ask, what is sleep? Is it a command internal to Ubuntu? Or docker command?

Comment: @Faraz It's a linux shell command, it's not specific to docker.

Answer (score 25):

My few cents on the subject. Assuming that `kubectl` is working then the closest command that would be equivalent to the docker command that you mentioned in your question, would be something like this.

```
$ kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu --restart=Never --command sleep infinity
```

Above command will create a single `Pod` in `default` namespace and, it will execute `sleep` command with `infinity` argument -this way you will have a process that runs in foreground keeping container alive.

Afterwords, you can interact with `Pod` by running `kubectl exec` command.

```
$ kubectl exec ubuntu -it -- bash
```

This technique is very useful for creating a Pod resource and ad-hoc debugging.

Comment: Works great. No need for the `--restart=Never`, just call `kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu  -- sleep infinity`

Comment: or if you want to do old fashioned thicker commands you can always do something like `kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- /bin/sh -c  'i=0; while true; do echo "$i: $(date)"; i=$((i+1)); sleep 1; done;'`

Answer (score 15):

I was able to get this to work with the command `sleep infinity` in Kubernetes, which will keep the container open. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935183/bash-infinite-sleep-infinite-blocking) for alternatives when that doesn't work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11368189)

Comment: @Will Sure it does. `sleep infinity` keeps the container open, providing the same type of functionality that the question asks about (for most types of containers). It also provides a link to alternatives for cases when that specific command doesn't work

Comment: This was from review. If you add the comment text there to the answer then it's a quality answer :) My initial flag/commend was based on saying your comment wasn't successful, making me think this was supposed to be a comment. Added a quick edit and upvoted.

Comment: "...sleep infinity in Kubernetes" is an uninformed statement. It implies that there is no  unix and no docker in the picture.

Answer (score 9):

Use this command inside you Dockerfile to keep the container running in your K8s cluster:

- CMD tail -f /dev/null

Answer (score 9):

add this : in template ->in spec-> in container ->in ports & after container port line

```
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "while :; do echo '.'; sleep 6 ; done"]
```

Comment: sharing the whole file with command would be more helpful to others instead of command.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, a pod with an initContainer failed to initialize. Running `docker ps -a` and then `docker logs exited-container-id-here` gave me a log message which `kubectl logs podname` didn't display. Mystery solved :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are many different ways for accomplishing this, but one of the most *elegant* one is:

```
kubectl run -i --tty --image ubuntu:latest ubuntu-test --restart=Never --rm /bin/sh
```

Comment: Why do you consider it the most elegant solution?

Comment: @mordowiciel, because it directly relates to docker command and it's not split into two commands like the most of the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I did a hack by putting it in background:

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl run hello -it --image ubuntu -- bash &
[2] 128461
```

Exec on pod `hello`

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl exec -it hello -- whoami
root
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl exec -it hello -- hostname
hello
```

Getting a shell

```
[root@localhost ~]# kubectl exec -it hello -- bash
root@hello:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Comment: The -it part is what I was missing! So, `kubectl run test-container -it --image alpine -- sh` gave me exactly what I was looking for, a pod with alpine running inside the cluster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This command may help

```
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep i infinity & wait"
```

Comment: what is `i` for in `sleep i infinity`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep images pre-cached in the nodes, I think that could be the idea, you can have a `daemonset` that distribute the pod image to all nodes or those that you are interested, and you can use `sleep infinity` to keep the containers alive and also avoid that the images to be cleaned up by `k8s GC`.
Note: Keep in mind the some docker images does not contains `/bin/sh` binary, for those you need a workaround. Sharing below the example where the `/bin/sh` binary is not present, if that is not your case, then just delete the `initContainers` and the volumes that shares the binary files to the containers. In the example `busybox` is used, you can also adjust the `initContainers` and use the one that contains the missing binary.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: image-cache
  namespace: default # adjust the namespace
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: image-cache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: image-cache
    spec:
      # Specify node affinity if you need it
      # Specify security context global if you need it
      initContainers:
        - name: busybox-musl
          image: busybox:musl
          command:
            - sh
          args:
            - -c
            - |
              echo "Copying binary..."
              cp /bin/busybox /usr/shared/binaries
              chown 1000:1000 /usr/shared/binaries/busybox
              chmod 775 /usr/shared/binaries/busybox
              echo "... Done."
          volumeMounts:
            - name: busybox-shared
              mountPath: /usr/shared/binaries
      containers:
        - name: container-name
          image: desired-container-image:version
          command:
            - /usr/shared/binaries/busybox
          args:
            - sleep
            - infinity
          volumeMounts:
            - name: busybox-shared
              mountPath: "/usr/shared/binaries"
      volumes:
        - name: busybox-shared
          emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Keep a Kubernetes pod open (medium article)](https://medium.com/@juan.mcpeek/keep-a-kubernetes-pod-open-c9ea5038337d)

Create a pod with `stdin: true`

Then `kubectl exec -it ubuntu -- /bin/bash`

Boom, you have a pod of whatever image you need running and staying open. Shell into it at will.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: ubuntu
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - image: ubuntu:latest
    name: ubuntu
    stdin: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
```