# Running Scrapy in Docker Container

Tags: docker

I am looking to run a Scrapy project in a docker container as part of a larger docker-compose application. My idea is to install Ubuntu base image, add all the dependencies and then get it going. Ideally I would like the container to continually run and when I want to run the Scrapy project I will run `docker exec` into it. The long term goal would be to have the Scrapy as a scheduled task running every day.

How would I go about this?

I've tried: `CMD ["/bin/sh"]` but the container exits straight away with code 0.

Answer (score 1):

Because /bin/sh exits if it see it's standard input closed and there is no script to run.

Here is a similar question that explains in detail what you need to do [How can I keep container running on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-container-running-on-kubernetes)

In short your command should be:

```
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```