# Copy files from completed Kubernetes batch jobs

Tags: kubernetes, jobs

I would like to copy the result from a `batch job` execution but `kubectl cp pod:/path /path` is not working, since the pod is in completed state.

I have the data stored in a PV.

How can I copy the results to my computer?

Looking forward to read your answers, many thanks

Comment: you'd have to create another pod to access the persistent volume, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375826/kubernetes-how-to-download-a-persistentvolumes-content

Comment: mount that pv on some busybox pod and copy the data

Comment: Great, I will do it or maybe mount NFS, so I can do it by mounting it in the local machine

Comment: I have created a new issue to get this functionality without using a PersistentVolume: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/111045
Please support me and give this issue a weight. Not less important please help me to find the persons who are able to bring this topic to success.