# Accessing Nexus repository manager password in a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, nexus3

I have installed [Sonatype nexus repository manager](https://github.com/sonatype/helm3-charts/tree/master/charts/nexus-repository-manager) in my Kubernetes Cluster using the helm chart.

I am using the [Kyma](https://kyma-project.io/) installation.

Nexus repository manager got installed properly and I can access the application.

But it seems the login password file is in a pv volume claim `/nexus-data` attached in the pod.

Now whenever I am trying to access the pod with `kubectl exec` command:

```
kubectl exec -i -t $POD_NAME -n dev -- /bin/sh
```

I am getting the following error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I understand that this issue is because of the image does not offer shell functionality.
Is there any other way i can access the password file present in the pvc?

Comment: If you use kubernetes 1.22, you could already use the debug container function. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`kubectl cp` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) but probably it won't work as the there is no shell inside the container.

You can't really access the  `pv` used by `pvc` directly in Kubernetes, but there is a simple work-around - just create another pod (with shell) with this  `pvc` mounted and access it. To avoid errors like `Volume is already used by pod(s) / node(s)` I suggest to schedule this pod on the same node as nexus pod.

1. Check on which node is located your nexus pod: `NODE=$(kubectl get pod <your-nexus-pod-name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}')`
2. Set nexus label for node: `kubectl label node $NODE nexus=here` (avoid using "yes" or "true" instead of "here"; [Kubernetes will read it as boolean, not as the string)](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/1748#issuecomment-428851117)
3. Get your nexus `pvc` name mounted on the pod by running `kubectl describe pod <your-nexus-pod-name>`
4. Create simple pod definition refereeing to nexus `pvc` from previous step:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: access-nexus-data
spec:
  containers:
    - name: access-nexus-data-container
      image: busybox:latest
      command: ["sleep", "999999"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nexus-data
          mountPath: /nexus-data
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: nexus-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: <your-pvc-name>
  nodeSelector:
    nexus: here
```

5. Access to the pod using  `kubectl exec access-nexus-data -it -- sh` and read data. You can also use earlier mentioned `kubectl cp` command.

If you are using some cloud provided Kubernetes solution, you can try to mount `pv` volume used by `pvc` to VM hosted on the cloud.

Source: [similar Stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375826/kubernetes-how-to-download-a-persistentvolumes-content/50381178#50381178)