# container does not start with status CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I am trying to run a simple ubuntu container in a kubernetes cluster. It keeps on failing with CrashLoopBackOff status. I am not even able to see any logs as in to find the reason for it.

my yaml file looks like following:

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
  labels:
     app: jubuntu
spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: jubuntu
    template:
      metadata:
         labels:
            app: jubuntu
      spec:
         containers:
            - name: ubuntu
              image: ubuntu
```

Comment: if you run a `kubectl describe pod <your-pod-name>`, what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using a `Deployment` that assumes you have a long-running task. In your case, it starts the container and immediately exits since there's nothing to be done there. In other words, this deployment doesn't make a lot of sense. You could add the following in the `containers:` field to see it running (still useless, but at least you don't see it crashing anymore):

```
command:
- sh
- '-c'
- "while true; do echo working ; sleep 5; done;"
```

See also [this troubleshooting guide](http://troubleshooting.kubernetes.sh/#poking-pods).

For your convenience, if you don't want to do it via editing a YAML manifest, you can also use this command:

```
$ kubectl run --image=ubuntu -- sh while true; do echo working ; sleep 5; done;
```

And if you're super curious and want to check if it's the same, then you can append the following to the run command: `--dry-run --output=yaml` (after `--image`, before `-- sh`).

Comment: the whole idea is to get the pod running with vanila ubuntu so that i could log on to it and install few tools over there.. i dont really need it to be a deployment, but even after changing the type to pod, the problem remains the same.

Comment: thanks for suggesting what i was missing. searching further for the article i came across this [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-container-running-on-kubernetes

Comment: Yeah, that answer is the same as I provided above, just in YAML and you've got it on the CLI. And yes, you're right that technically the same applies to a pod. The kubelet notices the container exits and considers it gone bad so re-starts it but since it's not a long-running process (while loop or simply sleep) it never actually comes up.

Comment: Updated the answer with it. Both things are equivalent.