# Docker build fails to resolve absolute path

Tags: reactjs, docker

I have a react app where I use absolute imports instead of relative imports (https://medium.com/@ktruong008/absolute-imports-with-create-react-app-4338fbca7e3d). Everything works as should on my local machine but when I try to build on docker it fails.

I have an .env file which contains `NODE_PATH='./'` and create-react-app is configured in such a way that its webpack configuration will automatically pick up ‘.env’ files and read the `NODE_PATH` environment variable, which can then be used for absolute imports so something like `src/components/NavBar`, resolves.

But when I try to build on docker, it doesn't resolve but throws this error.

```
Cannot find module: 'src/components/NavBar'. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: yarn add src/components/NavBar.
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Today is my first time working with Docker so I’m a noob.

Additional Info:

I use a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file.

I use react-app-rewired (https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) which basically helps you override create-react-app webpack configs without ejecting.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.15.1

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN mkdir /usr/invoicing

COPY . /usr/invoicing

WORKDIR /usr/invoicing

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    container_name: invoice-frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    networks:
      - frontend
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
networks:
  frontend:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

Comment: Could you please provide both `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`?

Comment: replace your  relative path  `NODE_PATH='./'` with a real absolute full path as viewed from inside the container ... keep in mind when launching a container its yaml volumes map full path on parent host machine to full path as viewed from inside the container ... its helpful to launch a container which does nothing just so you have something running which you can login to and view volumes inside ... details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31879013/147175

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks for the pointer; I used `docker exec -it (name-of-image)` and ran pwd to get the working directory and swapped the value in my NODE_PATH but still, doesn't resolve

Comment: @CarlosFrias please i've updated my post with docker-compose.yml and dockerfile

Comment: I used your configuration but I wasn't able to replicate the issue, maybe you're using an old built image, try running `docker-compose up --build`, to force a rebuild of the image from the `Dockerfile`, tell me if that works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I’ve found the problem and the solution:

Apparently, I named a folder `navBar` and when I renamed it to be `NavBar`, Git didn't detect a change in the foldername and didn't do anything about it. So on my local machine (which is a Mac), it shows NavBar but on Gitlab which uses git commits, it still appeared as `navBar` and cos Docker runs on Linux and Linux is case sensitive, the build fails.

This also explains why the build worked on my local machine. Mac’s filesystem hfplus is case insensitive so it didn't see a problem.

To solve the renaming problem; I used the `git mv` command. There’s a caveat tho; if you want to rename a `foldername` to `folderName` (ie change the case) on case insensitive file systems like Mac, you’ll get an error saying `fatal: renaming ‘foldername’ failed: Invalid argument.`

In order to rename the folder successfully, use this command.
`git mv foldername tempname && git mv tempname folderName`. This splits the process into two steps; first renaming the foldername to tempname and the renaming tempname to folderName.

Hopefully, this helps someone

Comment: ran into the same issue today and this post saved me.

Comment: Got the same issue - my local machine is Mac, and my CI/CD pipeline works on Linux. Spent around 2 days to solving the problem before I found your answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are building an image of your Next.js project:
When creating a project through the Next.js CLI with TypeScript, the CLI places TypeScript into dev dependencies.

So when building with `NODE_ENV=production` and `next build`, the dev dependencies are not used. If TypeScript is not used, your `tsconfig.json` is not processed, so all of your absolute paths are not computed.

I encountered this issue with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20.11.0-bullseye-slim

# Create destination directory
WORKDIR /app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Set environment variables & args for deployment
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
ARG ENV=production
ENV ENV=${ENV}
ARG PORT=3000
ENV PORT=${PORT}
ARG BACK_HOST
ENV BACK_HOST=${BACK_HOST}

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE ${PORT}:${PORT}

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

So removing the following lines from the Dockerfile solved my absolute path problem:

```
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```