# Helm kubernetes on AKS Pod CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy a simple nodejs application via helm kubernetes on Azure Kubernetes Service, but after pulling my image it says `CrashLoopBackOff`.

Here's what I have tried so far:

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 32000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**My `server.js`:**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

const PORT = 32000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world from container.\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

I have pushed this image to ACR.

> **New Update:** Here's the complete output of `kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`:

```
Name:               myrel02-mychart06-5dc9d4b86c-kqg4n
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aks-nodepool1-19665249-0/10.240.0.6
Start Time:         Tue, 05 Feb 2019 11:31:27 +0500
Labels:             app.kubernetes.io/instance=myrel02
                    app.kubernetes.io/name=mychart06
                    pod-template-hash=5dc9d4b86c
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.2.5
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/myrel02-mychart06-5dc9d4b86c
Containers:
  mychart06:
    Container ID:   docker://c239a2b9c38974098bbb1646a272504edd2d199afa50f61d02a0ce335fe60660
    Image:          registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app:0.5
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app@sha256:4faab280d161b727e0a6a6d9dfb52b22cf9c6cd7dd07916d6fe164d9af5737a7
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 05 Feb 2019 11:39:56 +0500
      Finished:     Tue, 05 Feb 2019 11:40:22 +0500
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:  cluster06-ary-2a187a-dc393b82.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io
      KUBERNETES_PORT:               tcp://cluster06-ary-2a187a-dc393b82.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io:443
      KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP:       tcp://cluster06-ary-2a187a-dc393b82.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io:443
      KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST:       cluster06-ary-2a187a-dc393b82.hcp.centralus.azmk8s.io
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gm49w (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-gm49w:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gm49w
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From                               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  10m                    default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned default/myrel02-mychart06-5dc9d4b86c-kqg4n to aks-nodepool1-19665249-0
  Normal   Pulling    10m                    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  pulling image "registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app:0.5"
  Normal   Pulled     10m                    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Successfully pulled image "registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app:0.5"
  Warning  Unhealthy  9m30s (x6 over 10m)    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.244.2.5:80/: dial tcp 10.244.2.5:80: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Created    9m29s (x3 over 10m)    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Created container
  Normal   Started    9m29s (x3 over 10m)    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Started container
  Normal   Killing    9m29s (x2 over 9m59s)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Killing container with id docker://mychart06:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Unhealthy  9m23s (x7 over 10m)    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.2.5:80/: dial tcp 10.244.2.5:80: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Pulled     5m29s (x6 over 9m59s)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Container image "registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/docker-web-app:0.5" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    22s (x33 over 7m59s)   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-19665249-0  Back-off restarting failed container
```

> **Update:** `docker logs CONTAINER_ID` output:

```
> nodejs@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node server.js

Running on http://0.0.0.0:32000
```

How can I avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, you need to pull the logs from the pod or from the pod controller and identity the issue: `kubectl logs podname` and\or `kubectl describe pods podname`

Comment: You will probably find this much easier to debug if you `docker run` the image locally.  (I feel like I’ve seen another SO question where the space after the `[` was a problem.) If you’re not able to work it out, it would be really helpful if you could add the deployment spec to the question.

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, I have added a little bit `log` info above in the question.

Comment: according to output you container finished with exit code 0. so it stopped on its own

Comment: How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, when I run this image using `docker run` it's working correclty.

Comment: well show logs from the container?

Comment: do I need to run `docker logs CONTAINER_ID` ?

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, I have added the output of `docker logs` above.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from `kubectl describe pod` command output, your Container inside the Pod has been already completed with exit code 0 (@4c74356b41 mentioned about it in the comments).  `Reason: Completed`, which states about successful completion without any errors/problems. However the life cycle of the Pod was very short, therefore Kubernetes continuously schedules new Pods but Liveness and Readiness probes are still failing on the container healthiness.

To keep the Pod running, you must specify a task (process) inside to the container for the ability of continuously running. There are lots of discussions and solutions available on how to solve that kind of issue, more hints can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes).

Answer (score 0):

kubectl logs command only works if the pod is up and running. If they are not, you can use the kubectl events command. It will give you some log of events and sometimes (in my experience) will give you also clues on what is going on.

```
kubectl get events -n <your_app_namespace> --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp'
```

By default it does not sort the events, hence the --sort-by flag.