# Pod Stuck on `CrashLoopBackOff` even though it should go into /bin/bash

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, minikube

I'm running a `Kubernetes` cluster with `minikube` and my deployment (or individual Pods) won't stay running even though I specify in the `Dockerfile` that it should stay leave a terminal open (I've also tried it with `sh`). They keep getting restarted and sometimes they get stuck on a `CrashLoopBackOff` status before restarting again:

```
FROM ubuntu

EXPOSE 8080

CMD /bin/bash
```

My deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sleeper-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sleeper-world
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sleeper-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sleeper-pod
        image: kubelab
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

All in all, my workflow follows (`deploy.sh`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Cleaning

kubectl delete deployments --all
kubectl delete pods --all

# Building the Image

sudo docker build \
    -t kubelab \
    .

# Deploying

kubectl apply -f sleeper_deployment.yml
```

By the way, I've tested the Docker Container solo using `sudo docker run -dt kubelab` and *it does stay up*. Why doesn't it stay up within `Kubernetes`? Is there a parameter (in the YAML file) or a flag I should be using for this special case?

Comment: The `bash` process is probably exiting immediately, because there's no way to type anything into it.  You should run some actual server process inside the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. Original Answer (but edited...)

If you are familiar with Docker, check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/).

If you are looking for an equivalent of `docker run -dt kubelab`, try `kubectl run -it kubelab --restart=Never --image=ubuntu /bin/bash`. In your case, with the Docker `-t` flag: [Allocate a pseudo-tty](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/). That's why your Docker Container stays up.

Try:

```sh
kubectl run kubelab \
    --image=ubuntu \
    --expose \
    --port 8080 \
    -- /bin/bash -c 'while true;do sleep 3600;done'
```

Or:

```sh
kubectl run kubelab \
    --image=ubuntu \
    --dry-run -oyaml \
    --expose \
    --port 8080 \
    -- /bin/bash -c 'while true;do sleep 3600;done'
```

## 2. Explaining what's going on (Added by Philippe Fanaro):

As stated by @David Maze, the `bash` process is going to exit immediately because the artificial terminal won't have anything going into it, a slightly different behavior from Docker.

If you change the `restart` Policy, it will still terminate, the difference is that the Pod won't regenerate or restart.

One way of doing it is (pay attention to the tabs of `restartPolicy`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kubelab-pod
  labels:
    zone: prod
    version: v1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kubelab-ctr
    image: kubelab
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  restartPolicy: Never
```

However, this will **not** work if it is specified inside a `deployment` YAML. And that's because deployments force regeneration, trying to always get to the *desired state*. This can be confirmed in the [Deployment Documentation Webpage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):

> Only a [`.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) equal to `Always` is allowed, which is the default if not specified.

## 3. If you really wish to force the Docker Container to Keep Running

In this case, you will need something that doesn't exit. A *server-like process* is one example. But you can also try something mentioned in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770783/4756173):

```
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

> This will keep your container alive until it is told to stop. Using trap and wait will make your container **react immediately to a stop request**. Without trap/wait stopping will take a few seconds.

Comment: Apparently, there is no way to actually putting this into a *YAML deployment file*. In the [Deployment Documentation webpage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) it's even stated that inside a deployment the only value allowed is the default: `Always`: 

> Only a `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` equal to `Always` is allowed, which is the default if not specified.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, check now.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by checking it again.

Comment: I hope you agree the edit improves the answer. If you accept it (or come up with something better), I will accept your answer.

Comment: Of course I accepted, I would like to point that second command is to get yaml for your deployment, I think it is the best way to get yaml for further editions. You might be also interested in [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind)

Comment: But how would it be better than `kubectl apply -f <file_name>.yml`? (I'm sorry, I'm a beginner.) I'll check out the [kind](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind) library later on. If you think it adds to the answer, please edit on top of my edit.

Comment: With `kubectl run ... --dry-run -oyaml` it is exactly the same if you apply yaml file, but you have to somehow create it so this command will render it for you and then you can pipe it to file and add what you need.