# Kubernetes inspecting a stopped Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In Kubernetes I have a Pod that is no longer running, eg in `Completed`/`Terminated` state.

I have [`describe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) and [`logs`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec), but sometimes you need to [`exec`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) into a Pod to debug problems.  This isn't always possible to do in time whilst the Pod was running.

Is there a way to inspect a Pods filesystems post-mortem?
Or a way to bring a Pod back replacing the CMD/ENTRYPOINT with `/bin/bash` or similar to have a poke around to see what happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can check previous logs of a pod by using `--previous` flag:

1. `kubectl logs my-pod --previous` [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods)
2. `kubectl logs my-pod -c my-container --previous` [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#interacting-with-running-pods)

On an event where you want to keep the container inside the pod alive then use the below code:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    # Just spin & wait forever
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]` [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40093356/4451944)

above the important lines are
`# Just spin & wait forever
 command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
 args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]`

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful!  Bringing back an identical pod with a sleep command works well, but when there are several ConfigMaps, Volumes, Secrets etc... it can be a lot of work to manually recreate it as it was.  Am just experimenting with parsing the manifest from `kubectl get pod myPod -o yaml` into something that can be spun up again using your sleep command, eg `kubectl apply -f myPodResurrected.yaml`.

Comment: this might be helpful https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#running-a-command-in-a-shell