# Skaffold 1.4.0: "Skipping deploy due to sync error: copying files:"

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Using:

- Skaffold 1.4.0
- minikube 1.6.2
- kubectl: client 1.15.5 and server 1.17.0
- Django 3.0.3
- Python 3.8.2

I just recently started receiving this error as I'm working on a Django API. Anytime I save after making a change I get a:

```
WARN[0234] Skipping deploy due to sync error: copying files: Running [kubectl --context minikube exec api-deployment-6946878554-n7lc2 --namespace default -c api -i -- tar xmf - -C / --no-same-owner]
 - stdout: 
 - stderr: error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("api")
: exit status 1
```

Not sure what has changed to cause this. I have to do a `CTRL + C` to shutdown Skaffold and restart it to get the changes to be reflected.

This is my `skaffold.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta15
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: postgres
      context: postgres
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "***/*.sql"
            dest: .
    - image: testappacr.azurecr.io/test-app-api
      context: api
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "***/*.py"
            dest: .
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - manifests/dev-ingress.yaml 
      - manifests/postgres.yaml
      - manifests/api.yaml
```

Also the `api.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: testappacr.azurecr.io/test-app-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: PGUSER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGUSER
            - name: PGHOST
              value: postgres-cluster-ip-service
            - name: PGPORT
              value: "1423"
            - name: PGDATABASE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGDATABASE
            - name: PGPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: PGPASSWORD
            - name: SECRET_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: SECRET_KEY
            - name: DEBUG
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: test-app-secrets
                  key: DEBUG
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/mnt/test-app"
            name: file-storage
      volumes:
        - name: file-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: file-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: api
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

Any suggestions about what might be going on here?

Comment: Can you check if the container called "api" on "api-deployment-6946878554-n7lc2" pod is up and running at the time you are saving changes?

Comment: @Nick Yes, I've verified it is running. It has `READY: 1/1` and `STATUS: Running`.

Comment: Can you connect to that container in interactive terminal and run that command directly? I'm trying to exclude the possibility of broken container and command

Comment: It looks like it is probably due to the `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` I have on the `api.yaml`. When it hits that error, which doesn't happen all the time, I looked and occasionally the pods restart, but for the part they `crashbackloop`. I checked the logs and just said the `livenessProbe` and `readinessProbe` were failing. I commented them out and so far have been fine, but it has only been a little while.

Comment: I assume it works fine now. In such a case it would be good if you can post an answer to your question (so it won't be orphaned:) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue was caused by my `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` in the `api.yaml`.

```
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 5000
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
```

Now I don't get this error.

However, the reason I had them there in the first place was because `skaffold` will sometimes boot up the database after the API, causing it to fail. So that is the trade off in my case: without `probes` DB occasionally boots after API causing failure or have them and it more frequently results in the error related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For others completely new to Kubernetes, note that this error can occur simply because your server script/process completed before the skaffold-sync command was attempted; kubernetes interprets the ending of your process as meaning that it failed, and therefore closes the container (or at least makes it so that skaffold is unable to make a call into it to apply the file sync).

More info here: [How can I keep a container running on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870222/how-can-i-keep-a-container-running-on-kubernetes)

So the solution is to "keep your process alive", by having it run a sleep-and-log loop or something. (even if it has no real work left to do, eg. if you just wrote a test script that logs and exits)

NodeJS example:

```js
console.log("Test server-script started!");

// loop forever, to keep process alive, so kubernetes doesn't kill the container, so skaffold-sync can work
while (true) {
    console.log("Keep-alive loop. Time:", Date.now());
    await new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
```