# How to retain docker alpine container after "exit" is used?

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

Like for example if I use command `docker run -it alpine /bin/sh`
it starts a terminal after which I can install packages and all. Now when I use `exit` command it goes back to the terminal. (main one)

So how can I access the same container again? 
When I run that command again, I get a fresh alpine.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Keep Docker Container Running After Starting Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775266/how-to-keep-docker-container-running-after-starting-services)

Comment: may be not a duplicate question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pull an image

```
docker image pull alpine
```

See that image is there

```
docker image ls   OR  just docker images
```

see what is inside the alpine

```
docker run alpine ls -al
```

Now your question is how to stay with the shell

```
docker container run -it alpine /bin/sh
```

You are inside shell script command line. Some distribution may have bash shell.

```
 docker exec -it 5f4 sh
 / # (<-- you can run linux command here!)
```

At this point, you can use command line of alpine and do

```
ls -al
```

type exit to come out-
You can run it in detached mode and it will keep running.

With exec command  we can login again

```
docker container run -it -d alpine /bin/sh
```

verify that it is UP and copy the FIRST 2 -3 digits of the container ID

```
docker container ls
```

login with exec command

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER ID or just 2-3 digits> sh
```

You will need to STOP otherwise it will keep running.

```
docker stop <CONTAINER ID>
```

Answer (score 36):

The container lives as long as the specified run command process is still running. When you specify to run `/bin/sh`, once you exit, the sh process will die and so will you container.

If you want to keep your container running, you have to keep the process inside running. For your case (I am not sure what you want to acheive, I assume you are just testing), the following will keep it running

```
docker run -d --name alpine alpine tail -f /dev/null
```

Then you can `sh` into the container using

```
docker exec -it alpine sh
```

Comment: So how i can i keep it running and get back to it later

Comment: @user8094908 answer udpated.

Comment: Here is what i want to do...I want to run alpine in docker, then install git,ant and maven on that command line. So when i exit the container, the installed   things should stay and when i come back i could continue my work...

Comment: @yamenK, I would avoid `ping localhost` for two reasons, one is constant log output and second it is actually doing something. You should be using variants which do nothing and print nothing. Bash infinite loop using ` while true; sleep 1; done` or the easier one to remember for me `tail -f /dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

## Run Alpine in background

```
$ docker run --name alpy -dit alpine
$ docker ps
```

## Attach to Alpine

```
$ docker attach alpy
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `docker start`, which allows you to start a stopped container. If you didn't name your container, you'll need to get it's name/id using `docker ps`.

For example,

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND
4c01db0b339c        alpine                       bash    

$docker start -i -a 4c01db0b339c
```

Comment: just prints the container id and does nothing

Comment: @user8094908 Ah oops! That just starts the container. You also need to attach to it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot i  will bookmark this page for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is below

```
docker run -d --name myalpine alpine tail -f /dev/null
```

This would make sure that your container doesn't die. Now whenever you need to install packages inside you just get inside the container using sh

```
docker exec -it myalpine /bin/sh
```

If for some reason your container dies, you can still start it again using

```
docker start myalpine
```

Comment: It starts it in the background. I replaced you `-it` with `-d` which means detached mode.   `-d, --detach                         Run container in background and print container ID`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess there are many ways to do the same. I will check this method too.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that probably is a little easier to remember. Simply use the `sleep infinity` ending (also supported by a few other Linux distributions) instead of the `tail -f /dev/null` ending suggested elsewhere:

```
docker run -d --name my_container alpine sleep infinity
```

Once you have the container running, you can attach the container to the terminal session using the `exec` parameter:

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/sh
```